# Emacs ignores Ctrl+/ keystroke

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal.app

When I run emacs on an ssh session to a Linux box via Terminal.app, it ignores `Ctrl + /` key combo (undo). How to stop this?

Answer (score 2):

This is part of the reason I don't use Terminal.app anymore and use rxvt under Xquartz. You'll need a way to either modify the way Terminal.app handles ctrl/meta character ([this question](https://superuser.com/questions/40000/mac-os-x-terminal-remap-command-keys) has a solution for that), or use an alternate term application.

Comment: Well, I already have all other keys behave properly (e.g. C-c, C-c), but not C-/ for some reason.